# Attempting to rename row names using mysql / regex

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to rename rows in a column using mysql and possibly regex or replace? 
The names are setup like this...
FL_**Miamidade***1026295
I need them to look like this...
FL***Miami-Dade**_1026295

I am thinking the sql statement would look something like this, but not sure how to do the replace part...

```
UPDATE tableName
WHEN columnName LIKE '%Miamidade%'
Would need regex to somehow change only the middle part of the string
```

Comment: Can you provide your data and desired results as a table.  And are they all for Miami-Dade?

Comment: Hi, I would want the sql statement to go through all rows in the table for column1, and wher ever it sees 'Miamidade' replace to 'Miami-Dade'. This string is likely in the middle of a string, such as FROM: FL_Miamidade1026295, TO: FL_Miami-Dade_1026295

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is the only pattern you are looking to replace, you can simply use `replace`.

```
UPDATE tableName
SET columnName = replace(columnName,'Miamidade','Miami-Dade_')
WHERE columnName LIKE '%Miamidade%'
```

If Miamidade has to be case-senstitive (meaning miamidade is invalid), use case sensitive collation based on the database settings.

Eg:

```
WHERE columnName LIKE '%Miamidade%' COLLATE latin1_general_cs
```

or use `regexp binary`

```
WHERE columnName REGEXP BINARY 'Miamidade'
```

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you!!  for some reason the 'COLLATE latin1_general_cs' threw an error. but I removed it and the capitals worked regardless

Comment: @WilliamHowley .. the error is because you have a different setting for default collation. You can use `regexp binary` for case sensitive matches in that case.